# Unable to have Vim-like C-W f for Screen's copy-mode

Tags: vim, gnu-screen, copy-mode

I want open a path to vim from Screen's copy-mode by

```
Ctrl-A f
```

similarly as I can open external files in Vim by

```
Ctrl-W f
```

**How can you open a path in Vim in Screen's copy-mode?**

---

*--- Thank you for Samuil to get the crux move*

Let's assume mouse is at PATH/file in the following code which represents display when Screen is on

```
text[space]PATH/file[space]text
```

I press ^A f at PATH/file. It should save the PATH of the file to /tmp/screenCopyFile such that we can use `cat` in the following command which the `^A f` should start:

```
^A: exec vim `cat PATH/file`
```

I run the command manually unsuccessfully. It did not expand the cat command, but it opens a file called cat.

In other words, we want to make the letter `f` stands for

```
exec vim `cat /tmp/screenCopyFile`
```

by binding in .screenrc.

**Thank you Rampion for your answer!**

Comment: That's why I proposed using additional script for it. `cat file` is not expanded, because it's shell feature, which screen's :exec command lack.

Comment: @samuil: How can you paste a PATH from a file to the : -mode in Screen from an external file without cat?

Comment: If you have 'PATH/file' in your pastbuffer you can write it down to file and run vim `cat /tmp/screenCopyFile` from your script without PATH. If you want to select filename only, you can add `pwd` to your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's a solution:

Put the following in `/path/to/edit-file-under-cursor.screen`:

```
# edit-file-under-cursor.screen

# prevent messages from slowing this down
msgminwait 0
# copy path starting at cursor
stuff " Ebe "
# write the path to a file
writebuf /tmp/screen-copied-path
# open that file in vim in a new screen window
screen /bin/sh -c 'vim `cat /tmp/screen-copied-path`'
# turn message waiting back on
msgminwait 1

# vi: ft=screen
```

Then add this line to your `.screenrc`:

```
# bind CTRL-f to open the file starting at the cursor
# when in copy mode
bindkey -m ^f source /path/to/edit-file-under-cursor.screen
```

(changing the `/path/to/` appropriately)

Then, to use, make sure you restart `screen` (or reload the `.screenrc`).
Enter copy mode with `^A[`, cursor to the first character of a filename,
then hit `CTRL-f`.

I've tested this, and it works for me, so tell me if you have any issues.

If you want to see how I knew how to do this, check `man screen` to 
see how all the various commands work.

One improvement that could be made is to be able to find the beginning of a path, but I couldn't do that reliably with only screen's copy mode movement commands (e.g. anything that moved to the first `/` of "`/a/path`" moved to the `|` of "`|/a/path`")

This is due to the limitations of `screen`'s movement commands in copy mode:

```
Movement keys:
  h, j, k, l move the cursor line by line or column by column.
  0, ^ and $ move to the leftmost column, to the first or last non-whitespace character on the line.
  H, M and L move the cursor to the leftmost column of the top, center or bottom line of the window.
  + and - positions one line up and down.
  G moves to the specified absolute line (default: end of buffer).
  | moves to the specified absolute column.
  w, b, e move the cursor word by word.
  B, E move the cursor WORD by WORD (as in vi).
  C-u and C-d scroll the display up/down by the specified amount of lines while preserving the cursor position. (Default: half screen-full).
  C-b and C-f scroll the display up/down a full screen.
  g moves to the beginning of the buffer.
  % jumps to the specified percentage of the buffer.
...
Searching:
  / Vi-like search forward.
  ? Vi-like search backward.
  C-a s Emacs style incremental search forward.
  C-r Emacs style reverse i-search.
```

So if we changed the `stuff` line above to

```
stuff "Bw Ebe "
```

it would move to the start of a path, but it would also include any non-whitespace junk that came before the path.  So as long as all your paths are whitespace delimited (on both sides) this should work.

Actually

```
stuff "B//^M E?/^Me "
```

seems to work fairly well, since that uses searching to find the first and last `/` (type the `^M` in vim by hitting CTRL-v, then enter).  I haven't tested all the edge cases, but it seems to work for:

```
 /a/path
 #/a/path
 /a/path#
```

However, it's going to fail for

```
 a/relative/path
```

Comment: @rampion: Thank you for your answer! The code also works for me. --- Could you please paste the code which you described your last paragraph? I will try to find the problem.

Comment: @rampion: The command "Bw Ebe" seems to be the most useful command of the rest. --- I am testing it to see if it has any flaws.

Comment: I noticed one bug. It would be useful to get the end character of the match to be also "," and ".". This would help you in reading manuals.

Comment: In that case, you might want to just drop the `stuff` line, highlight the path manually, copy it to a register, then hit the key combo to open the copied path in vim.

Comment: @rampion: Do you mean to copy the path in Copy-mode, and then hit `Ctrl-A Esc Ctrl-f`? --- This method did not work for me: the problem is that I am not sure about coping to register.

Comment: @rampion: I found another bug with long PATHs. I opened a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081943/unable-to-get-screen-see-the-current-working-directory-when-opening-to-vim

Answer (score 1):

I do not know vim too good, but with a few commands it should be done easily.
When you already have filename in your pastebuffer, you can use these useful commands:

```
^A : writebuf /tmp/.screenpomfile
^A : exec vim parameters
```

I do not know how to make `vim` read filename from file (I think it is possible), but you could `:exec` your own script written in a shell able to parse `` `expr `` ` expressions:

```
#!/bin/sh
vim `cat /tmp/.screenpomfile`
```

Later you can bind your own keys to these actions, and use them quite effectively.

Comment: @samuil: You can make Vim read filename from file by moving your cursor on top of the file with its exact path and press Ctrl-w f at normal mode.

Comment: @Masi: by "file" I didn't mean file opened with vim, but one saved on disk. Using this ^w f shortcut makes no sense in this case.